# Is there a way to get chrome driver to work on AWS lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers, chalice

I'm trying to get a simple web scraper to run-in AWS lambda but I'm facing a blocker where  the chromedriver I'm using which is the [latest](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=93.0.4577.15/) version exists with the following error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 127
```

I've tried different webDrivers but still getting the same error.
Any ideas why this might be happening?
Note: I'm using AWS Lambda Layers to store the binary and pointing to it through

```
chrome_driver_path = "/opt/chromedriver"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.125 Safari/537.36")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, chrome_options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you create a custom image with the chrome driver working
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html